# Is it appropriate to downvote a question without closevoting it

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about the scenarios where a question might be downvoted but not closed.

For me an upvote to a question is about if I would be interested in knowing the answer.

Downvotes for questions however seem to have no real rational outside wanting the question closed.

I think however downvoted questions do draw attention to questions needing to be closed.

**Is there any scenario where a questions should be downvoted but not closed**

on a sidenote, it would be really interesting to know what poportion of downvoted questions are closed

**Edit**

Based on the help documentation question placed on hold should encourage the OP to edit the question to become more suitable. from this i take that the intention is a question which is poorly worded should be put `on hold` (`closed`) pending a suitable edit.

Comment: I swear I saw this distinction made clear on meta before...let me go look...

Comment: A better question is whether it's ever appropriate to do both…

Comment: @bjb568 i think yes as it acts as an oracle for things that obviously need closing

Comment: This is a very timely discussion, I am glad you threw this out there.  I will not answer it, however I would just like to point out that a heavily downvoted, non-closed question will still attract a drove of answerers who are looking for a quick reputation gain.  So what then is the purpose of an open, -10 question?  Is it to say to googlers, "avoid me!"?  Is it to to punish 1 rep users who can't go any lower?  Of course, I exaggerate because -10 questions do generally get closed. But, there is really minor penalty if any for getting downvoted on a question, especially for 1 rep users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on my recent voting history:

I would **closevote a question without a downvote** if:

- it's just a duplicate
- it's well written and it simply belongs on another stackexchange site
- has potential to be good but is too broad or lacks sufficient information or any other problem that makes it unanswerable as is

I would **downvote a question without a closevote** if (hm, there's a lot less of this case):

- very poorly written / sloppy (but still on topic)
- shows no research effort (and still on topic) - this often fits homework questions

I tried to find the old meta post I remember reading on this a while ago for more insight, though you might get some from the [privileges info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges):

> ### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy,
>   no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps
>   dangerously incorrect.
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost
>   you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.
>
> ### When should I vote to close a question?
>
> Questions should be closed by casting close votes if:
>
> - they are sufficiently similar to existing questions and would be answered identically to them.
> - they are unclear, too broad, or otherwise problematic to identifying the problem in a way that can be properly addressed by answerers
> - they are sufficiently off-topic, as outlined in the help center.

Answer (score 12):

Let's look at the downvote tool tip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

So, you can case a justifiable downvote if a post:

- Is unclear, in which case you can also vote to close it as "unclear what you're asking".
- Does not show any research effort or is not useful, in which case it might not fall under one of the close reasons, and thus can't / shouldn't be closed.

  Let's take [this somewhat arbitrarily picked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236234/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment).

  It doesn't show much research effort, as a simple Google search would give you a good idea of what that error means, and most likely lead you to the conclusion that `++x` can't be modified (even though there might not be an exact duplicate around).

  Or one might simply deem that question as not particularly useful, as the error could be considered pretty self-explanatory.

  This might not be the best example, as you can probably close that as unclear, since it's not entirely clear what OP wants to accomplish with that code sample (but that should be fairly easy to fix). Beyond that, I don't think any of the other close reasons hold.

Comment: I do see what you are saying, many questions are poor, i totally agree, but to rephrase my question a little why leave poor questions open? if there are poor questions that are un-closable shouldnt the close system be extended?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor The general idea (I believe) is to close questions that don't make the internet a better place. If a question only lacks research effort, that doesn't imply that it makes the internet a worse place - like the above question, no research effort, but having it exist somewhere that `++x` can't be modified is perhaps useful. (Although I personally struggle to accept that we should help people (by answering) who didn't show research effort in their questions - I guess the idea is that it shouldn't be about them, but rather about the site.)

Comment: I think that's the intent but i think that downvoting a question is really making the same statement. The help docs also *suggest* that if a question may have merit after some edits but not in its current state then it should be put on hold until suitable edits are made.

Comment: You should close a question that doesn't provide enough details to be answerable in its current state (in addition to questions that don't even remotely belong here, of course) - if there's too much ambiguity, or the OP got an error but didn't provide valid code to reproduce it, for example. Not showing research effort doesn't make the question unanswerable.

Answer (score 9):

I downvote a question that I don't think contributes positively to SO as a whole.  This doesn't mean that the question is *off-topic* or otherwise inappropriate for SO, just that is not a good question.

Like:

- Asking questions that are obviously not well-thought-out.
- Posting **massive** amounts of code.  There may be a great question in there, but you have to search through your code and give it to me; I'm not going to dig in there myself to find out what all your `foo`s and `bar`s mean.

For me, it depends on the question. I rarely downvote **and** flag an answer; I think they serve different purposes.  It may be overly pessimistic of me, but once a question is closed, I see very little potential in it being edited/reopened by either the community or its author.  This is why I downvote instead of flagging.  I flag questions that do not belong here based on content/subject, and downvote questions that belong but are not good.

I believe in giving the user a chance to better their question and I think that the chances of editing decrease when a question is "on hold", despite the encouraging text at the bottom.

Comment: I would close those as 'its unclear what you are asking' as they generally wont provide good search targets even if they do get good answers

Comment: If OP makes an edit making it a decent question, it's actually fairly likely to get reopened (from my experience, because of how the system handles this). The problem with just downvoting is that OP has little motivation to edit it (assuming they don't care about reputation) as they can still get answers all the same. So, if the question is unclear, lacking a proper description of the problem or a reproducing code sample or too broad or opinion-based the way it's been asked, we shouldn't leave it open.

Comment: A massive amount of code that you have to search through is unclear and should be closed as such. (For the benefit of passers-by. I am a different Louis. Maybe this is a sign I should change my user name here.)